# Why are my photos I am tagged in not showing up in my "Photos and Videos of You" section?

Tags: tags, photo-gallery, photos, facebook-page, facebook-apps

When I tag myself in my photos they do not show up on my profile pictures `"Photos and Videos of You"` section.

In the past any photo I tag of myself in my own album would show up there. I'm not sure if this is just an issue I am having or if others are having it too because when I tag others in my photos, it shows up on their page in their "Photos and Videos of You" section, but not in mine.

Comment: You can get help from Facebook for user / account / site problems at https://www.facebook.com/help/?page=220217228006012 - this is not the correct forum for those questions (see http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/faq#questions  for more information)

Answer (score 1):

if you go to the album the photos are tagged in if you look on the right hand side just under the photo it'll say "show on my profile" or something like that then click on that and they should show up.
i did this for most of my pictures but some of them didn't have that button so i'm still trying to figure out how to get those on my profile.